# Not able to get value of an integer after callback method response

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a method which makes an api call and parses response. I am getting integer value of current weather in onResponse method. I want to set this value to the textview but after onResponse method value doesnt preserve. I have made that variable as global too. And this class extends fragment so I am setting value in onViewCreated method.

here is the code of the method with logs...

```
public class HomeScreen extends Fragment{
int currentWeather = 0;

onViewCreated(){
 curWeather = ... initialisation.
 curWeather.setText(""+getCurrentWeather);
}

public int getCurrentWeather(){

    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    Request re = new Request.Builder().url(forecastURL).build();
    Call call = okHttpClient.newCall(re);
    call.enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            String jsonResponse = response.body().string();
            JSONObject forecast;
            JSONObject currently;
            try {
                forecast = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
                currently = forecast.getJSONObject("currently");
                currentTempFaron = (int) Math.round(currently.getDouble("temperature"));
                currentTempCelc = (currentTempFaron - 32) * 5 / 9;

                Log.d("weather in try", "" + currentTempCelc); // has weather value
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.d("weather in response", "" + currentTempCelc); // again has weather value.
        }
    });
return currentTempCelc; //nothing it has at this point after coming out of response.
}

}
```

Comment: Are you seeing errors or are your views just not updating?

Comment: did not understand sir...

Comment: my view is not updating as my method is returning deffault 0 value

Comment: Okay, do you know you're receiving a valid JSON response?

Comment: yes that is valid the values I am getting on log statements are perfect

Comment: Try `curWeather.setText(Integer.toString(currentTempCelc));` in `onResponse();`

Comment: In onresponse it says can't set value in on response...

Comment: Why not? What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: return `currentTempCelc` inside `onResponse`

Comment: Or try what @kishorejethava said. Basically, your issue is that `call.enqueue(new Callback{...})` is an asynchronous operation so you're updating the UI before it has finished obtaining the data you want to display.

Comment: Daniel: "only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch it's view"

Comment: Kishwer: "can not return. Value from a method with void return. Type."

Comment: set value in textview using main thread inside onresponse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this inside `onResponse()` after `Log.d("weather in response", "" + currentTempCelc);`:

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        curWeather.setText(Integer.toString(currentTempCelc));
    }
});
```

The issue here is that you were trying to update the UI thread from the background thread which is not allowed. You can use `runOnUiThread` for this purpose though.

Comment: As this is a fragment I have taken an activity object and put the code with activity.runOnUi.... method but it says "Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()".. on line Activity activity = new Activity();

Comment: @AalapPatel, wait, you can use `getActivity().runOnUiThread(etc)` for fragments and you're using a fragment. Did you try that first? In fact, I made it a point to put it in my answer since I saw that you had a fragment.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Handler` to update UI Component in `onResponse`

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        curWeather.setText(Integer.toString(currentTempCelc));
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make `curWeather` a member variable in the `Fragment`. Then call `setText` on `curWeather` inside your `onResponse` method.

```
public class HomeScreen extends Fragment{
int currentWeather = 0;
final TextView curWeather

onViewCreated(){
 curWeather = ... initialisation.
 // curWeather.setText(""+getCurrentWeather);
}

public int getCurrentWeather(){

    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    Request re = new Request.Builder().url(forecastURL).build();
    Call call = okHttpClient.newCall(re);
    call.enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            String jsonResponse = response.body().string();
            JSONObject forecast;
            JSONObject currently;
            try {
                forecast = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
                currently = forecast.getJSONObject("currently");
                currentTempFaron = (int) Math.round(currently.getDouble("temperature"));
                currentTempCelc = (currentTempFaron - 32) * 5 / 9;

                Log.d("weather in try", "" + currentTempCelc); // has weather value
                curWeather.setText(""+currentTempCelc);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.d("weather in response", "" + currentTempCelc); // again has weather value.
        }
    });
return currentTempCelc; //nothing it has at this point after coming out of response.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your Activity Context with method **getCurrentWeather()** .Then you can access the TextView and set the TextView.I tried this solution and it's worked for me.